# If $M\prec L_{\omega_1}$ then $M = L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ - we need a condition to prove it?

Tags: set-theory

I try to prove the exercise 13.17 in Jech:

> If $M\prec (L_{\omega_1},\in)$, then $M=L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha.$
>
> [Show that $M$ is transitive. Let $X\in M$. Let $f$ be the $<_L$-least mapping of $\omega$ onto $X$. Since $f$ is definable in $(L_{\omega_1},\in)$ from $X$, $f$ is in $M$. Hence $f(n)\in M$ for each $n$ and we get $X\subseteq M$.]

According to the hint, if $X\in M$ then $X$ is countable. Especially, since there is a definable (in $L_{\omega_1}$) bijection between $\omega$ and $X$, $X$ is countable in $L_{\omega_1}$. However, as I know, $\omega_1$ can be inaccessible in $L$ and in that case there is an (internally) uncountable set in $L_{\omega_1}$. In that case, in my opinion, we can not guarantee $X$ is countable so we can not certain the existence of such $f$.

Thus I think some conditions are omitted in the problem, such as assuming $V=L$. Have I misunderstood something? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, the $\omega_1$ in the problem should be $\omega_1^L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to *prove* that you need an additional assumption that $\omega_1=\omega_1^L$ is the following: suppose $\omega_1>\omega_1^L$. Fix $\alpha$ with $\omega_1^L<\beta<\omega_1$, and let $M$ be a countable-in-$L$ elementary substructure of $L_{\omega_1}$ with $\beta\in M$, which exists since $ZFC$ (which is true in $L$) proves the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem. Then since $M$ is countable in $L$ but $\beta$ is not countable in $L$ we must have $M$ not transitive - and hence $M\not= L_\alpha$ for any $\alpha$.

Conversely, if $\omega_1=\omega_1^L$ then the proof Jech gives works. So this is in fact exactly the assumption needed.