# Is Condensation lemma for relative contructibility on Jech's Set theory wrong?

Tags: set-theory

This is how Jech states the Condensation lemma for relative constructibility in *Set Theory, 4th ed.* (the latest edition I think) at page 193, Lemma 13.24:

> If $M \prec (L_\delta [A], \in, A \cap L_\delta [A])$ where $\delta$ is a limit ordinal, then the transitive collapse of $M$ is $L\gamma [A]$ for some $\gamma \leq \delta$.

Note that $A$ is an arbitrary set here. On Devlin's book *Constructibility* (p. 105), the statement is essentially the same, but instead of $L_\gamma[A]$ there is $L_\gamma [B]$, where $B = \operatorname{mos}[A]$ and $\operatorname{mos}$ is the collapsing function of $M$. Devlin's version makes more sense to me, and I'd say that the two versions contradict each other (Devlin also remarks that we might end up with a structure which is not in the $L[A]$ hierarchy).

Is Jech's statement wrong? Is there any weak additional condition which makes it correct? I think that assuming $A \subseteq \omega_1$ is still not sufficient.

Comment: The Mostowski collapse of a set of ordinals is an ordinal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't see how this is true in general. It depends on which structure the collapsing function is defined on. If $S$ is a set of ordinals, $S \subseteq M$ and $\operatorname{mos}_M$ is the the collapsing function of $M$, then $\operatorname{mos}_M [S] = S$, which is an ordinal iff $S$ is an ordinal.

Comment: You are considering a collapse of a larger structure. Sure. If you only collapse a set of ordinals, you get an ordinal.

Comment: Ok, but then I don't understand how your comment answers the question. In the question I say "where $B = \operatorname{mos}[A]$ and $\operatorname{mos}$ is the collapsing function of $M$". Am I missing something?

Comment: You can always assume $A$ is a set of ordinals, though.

Comment: Ok but that's still not sufficient because maybe $L_\gamma [A] \neq L_\gamma [\operatorname{mos}_M [A]]$ even if $A$ is a set of ordinals! Or, at least, I can't see why they should be equal in general!

Comment: There are two ways of defining relative constructibility. Does Jech define $L_\gamma[A]$ by setting $L_0[A]$ equal to the transitive closure of $A$ and then following the definition where for successor ordinals, $L_{\gamma+1}[A]$ is the set of all sets first-order definable over $\langle L_\gamma[A];\in\rangle?$ Or does he set $L_0[A]=\emptyset$ and then set $L_{\gamma+1}[A]$ to be the set of all sets first-order definable over $\langle L_\gamma[A];\in;A \cap L_\gamma[A]\rangle,$ with an extra one-place predicate in the language? (At limit ordinals, there's no difference in the definitions.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector He defines both of them: he denotes the first you mention by $L(A)$ and the second by $L[A]$. But actually I believe this is irrelevant for my question, because if $A$ is any set of ordinals then $L(A)=L[A]$, but I'm pretty sure that the issue with the statements can lead to a contradiction even if $A \subseteq \omega_1$.

Comment: This is almost surely true if $A \subseteq \omega_2$. I quote Devlin: "As we saw above, the condensation lemma for $L[A]$ does not in general lead to   structure in the $L[A]$ hierarchy. Thus we cannot prove GCH in $L[A]$ as we did for $L$. Indeed, if $\kappa$ were a cardinal such that $2^\kappa = \kappa^{++}$, we could let $A \subseteq \kappa^{++}$ code all subsets of $\kappa$, so $2^\kappa \geq \kappa^{++}$ would hold in $L[A]$."

Comment: @aerdna91 Thanks -- there is a difference, because the equality isn't true level by level: $L_\delta(A)$ can be different from $L_\delta[A],$ even for $A$ a set of ordinals.  In fact, $L_\delta[A]$ contains all ordinals less than or equal to an ordinal in $A,$ since it contains the transitive closure of $A.$  So the Mostowski collapse of $L_\delta[A]$ is the identity on all ordinals less than or equal to an ordinal in $A,$ and it will map $A$ to $A$ itself.  Is Devlin working with $L(A)$ rather than $L[A]?$

Comment: @MitchellSpector 1) I think you meant "In fact, $L_\delta (A)$". Your argument applies to $L_\delta (A)$, but not to the one with square brackets, since $L_\delta [A] \cap Ord = \delta$ always. 2) Devlin works with $L[A]$, i.e. the one with the additional unary predicate. The notation is the same as in Jech.

Comment: @ aerdna91 Yes, I had them backwards; I'm used to the opposite notation.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Kunen for example uses a different notation. With relative constructibility it's a whole mess. There are few sources, almost no proof (most facts are given as exercise), and apparently they even contradict each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a partial answer that's too long for a comment:

I think the given statement isn't true, at least if $V\ne L.$ Let $A$ be a set of uncountable ordinals that does not belong to $L,$ and suppose that $\delta$ is an ordinal greater than $\cup A$ such that $L_\delta[A]\models$ ZFC.  (We can get by with some finite subset of ZFC here, and so carry out this construction in ZFC, but I won't worry about that.)

We have $A \in L_\delta[A],$ so $L_\delta[A] \models V\ne L.$

Now let $M \prec (L_\delta [A], \in, A \cap L_\delta [A])$ be countable. Its Mostowski collapse $N$ contains no members of $A$ (since $A$ contains no countable ordinals, but all the ordinals in $N$ are countable).  If $N$ were $L_\gamma[A]$ for some $\gamma,$ then $\gamma$ would be countable. But $\gamma$ being countable implies $L_\gamma[A]=L_\gamma,$ so this is a model of $V=L,$ which contradicts the fact that $M\models V\ne L.$

Comment: This looks correct to me. I am 99% sure that Jech is not explicitly assuming $V=L$ for that theorem. And this is not the first error I see of this kind (see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904271/if-m-prec-l-omega-2-then-omega-1-cap-m-alpha-for-some-alpha-o). Thank you

Comment: I don't have Jech's book, but my guess is that this was intended to be formulated the way you mentioned Devlin did, with $L_\gamma[B]$ instead of $L_\gamma[A].$